# Section of the screen gets distorted and pixelated after a few hours

Tags: 10.10, xorg, video, ati, fglrx

I have a Dell 1464 and installed Ubuntu on an External drive. After using ubuntu, I realized that a section of 3 or more hours make my screen go pixelated (Actually the blend of colors seems to get distorted and looked hideous). I use ATI Radeon Mobility HD 5450 and have installed the required driver. I'm new to linux.

I'm using ubuntu 10.10, fglrx 2.8.780-ubuntu2

[image]

*Notice the dark area behind the guy. The color seems to get distored.*

Comment: If you could take a picture that would really help!

Comment: are you using the fglrx driver? Sounds like a problem with open-source drivers that I've experienced before.

Comment: Yes. Fglrx driver it is. After some time even video start to become pixelated, not just images and desktop !

Comment: please mention the version of ubuntu and fglrx driver.

Comment: Also, please make sure that this is an actual distortion via the videocard (f.e. by taking screenshots and looking at them) and not your screen.

Comment: As for the screenshot, I now limit my time of using the laptop to below 2 hours to make sure my card is ok. I'll try for some long run to test.Thanks for the responds guys.

Comment: It may be that this is a problem with your hardware, but I will reserve that judgement until I see the screenshot.

Comment: I've got something similar with my ATI X1400 in my laptop. After some time, my display begins to flicker white, making it after a short period of time unusable. The fix is to suspend the computer and wake it up again. @Roland: I think a software bug is much more likely, after all those drivers have been programmed by reverse-engineering the ATI drivers.

Comment: I can't see any kind distortion in your screenshot...but maybe that's just me.

Comment: Oh wait, do you mean the [red marked area](http://www.bonsaimind.org/fileStore/ync.png), because that looks like 'normal' jpg/mpg distortion/compression artefacts to me, and you can find them in the whole screenshot.

Comment: It still happens. I'll wait for an updated fglrx driver or something. Thanks for the responses guys, especially Bobby for trying to point out that there's nothing wrong with my laptop. Your consolation really helps.

Comment: This question has not information added in it for a very long time and probably describes a bug in old package versions. I have flagged it to a moderator so it can be closed. If you think that this is still a valid question and that you are still suffering for this issue you can always flag it so that it can be re-opened.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if there is nothing wrong with screenshot (I can't see it either), most probably problem is with hardware. Dell do have excellent bootable [diagnostics software](http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/format.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=gen&SystemID=XPS_M1210&os=LE30&osl=FR&deviceid=3841&typecnt=1&libid=13&releaseid=R133063&vercnt=2), you should try it. If it founds some problems, warranty service can help (if warranty is still valid).

Answer (score 0):

your driver seems to be really outdated, i suggest to install the new one from AMD ATI.

refer to this page http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Maverick_Installation_Guide for further notes.